# How to retrieve unique relationship of Entities in Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, entity, nsfetchrequest

There must be an easier way to do this.  I have search and search but can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

Let's say we have a relationship like this
EntityA<-->>EntityB

If I create 2 instance of EntityA with 3 instances of Entity B for each.

In my viewcontroller that displays all EntityB for each EntityA, it displays all 6 instead of the 3 related to it.

The only way I can get it to display correctly is if I pass a pointer from one controller to another:

```
viewController2.entityA = viewController1.entityA;
```

and then retrieve the results in the following manner:

```
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[entityA.entityBs allObjects]];
```

I was under the impression that if you initially fetch a parent entity, the subsequent fetches are based on that rather than return all.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, passing the instance of entityA to the second view controller, and then using its entityBs property to get the values (as you have in your code) will be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *weightEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:[[yourCoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:weightEntity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"EntityA.name LIKE %@", @"EntityAName"]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [[yourCoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

This way, you are only requesting for only those Entities B that belongs to a given Entity A.

Comment: This would imply that I have to explicitly spell out the value of EntityAs attribute "name" in the query string (@"decision.decisionName LIKE %@", @"DecisionX").  right?

Comment: If you have a name attribute, that's just an example, you might use an id or whatever, something to differentiate your A Entities, but yes, you can pass that number/string to the new view controller and do it this way.